# Text always on two lines

Tags: javascript, html, css, wordpress-theming

I am making theme for Wordpress and my client wants blog titles always on 2 lines, even if there are only two words. Is it possible to somehow split the string always in middle? It should work something like this:

```
= = = = = = = = = = = = = = =
=                           =
=    Short                  =
=    title                  =
=                           =
= = = = = = = = = = = = = = =

= = = = = = = = = = = = = = =
=                           =
=    A little               =
=    longer title           =
=                           =
= = = = = = = = = = = = = = =

= = = = = = = = = = = = = = =
=                           =
=    long title             =
=    with more words        =
=                           =
= = = = = = = = = = = = = = =
```

Comment: you can use `<br/>` where ever you want to break the line.

Comment: *How* (according to which principles) should the title be split? Please be explicit. You probably mean that the lines should have as close to each other as possible in length.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bad practice but fine for example:

```
// Split your title to words:
var s = 'long title with more words'.split(' ');

if (s.length > 1) {

    // Add '<br>' into the center:
    s.splice(parseInt(s.length / 2) - 1, 0, '<br>');

    // Here is your result. Update HTML tag:
    console.log(s.join(' '));

} else {
    console.log(s + '<br>&nbsp;');
}
```

Or you can do it right from PHP:

```
<?php

$s = explode(' ', 'long title with more words');

if (count($s) > 1) {

    array_splice($s, intval(count($s) / 2) - 1, 0, '<br>');

    echo implode(' ', $s);

} else {
    echo $s[0], '<br>&nbsp;';
}
```

Comment: But it's not under php tag

Answer (score 0):

Many ways to do it.

**HTML**

- Use `br` tag

**JAVASCRIPT**

- Get div's text and using `text` method
- Split it using `split(" ")` method
- Divide the resultant array's length
- Print first half in first div
- Another half in next div

Comment: Yeah, but how to always break in the middle?

Comment: split array length is number of words. length/2 ll split in the middle always. got it??

Comment: I just give the idea. If OP wants code, i ll add it. I thought its a basic logic.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `<br/>` to break text

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/9s7ab/)**

```
<div>short
    <br/>title</div>
<div>A little
    <br/>longer title</div>
<div>long title
    <br/>with more words</div>
```

CSS

```
div {
    width:150px;
    height:80px;
    border:2px dotted;
    margin:10px;
    text-align:center;
}
```